# What is wrong with this PathBindable?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to send an object of my model as a parameter on a `GET` of `PlayFramework`

I created the `case class Game`, that looks something like this:

```
case class Game(name: String, url: String){

}
```

And when I tried to send it as a parameter to my method like this (routes file):

```
GET     /trophies/:game             controllers.Application.trophies(game: model.Game)
```

It told me I needed a `PathBindable` object, so I did some research and came with an implementation I thought was valid:

```
case class Game(name: String, url: String) implements PathBindable[Game] {
    def bind(key: String, value: String): Game = {
        val text = value.split(";")
        Game(text(0), text(1))
    }

    def unbind(key: String, game: Game): String = {
        game.name + ";" + game.url
    }

    def javascriptUnbind(): String = ??? 
    def unbind(x$1: String): String = ???
}
```

To bind it I create a `Game` from the string divided with the `;` and to unbind it I just create the divided String.

When I use it I get a `Bad Request`, stating that the Action was not found, but it exists, as I displayed on the routes file snippet above.

Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Is `bind` supposed to return an `Either`? Try adding `override` before `def`.

Comment: check the API..  should return `Either` http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable

Comment: It is strange that you get a Bad Request (Response code 400) instead of 400 not found. Can you give us an example case (i.e. game and URL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you used the PathBindable from the [Java API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/mvc/PathBindable.html) and missed the noarg constructor. but you need the [Scala API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable).

In addition make sure that your game path representation is URL encoded (it should not contain raw slashes "/") or would not match. But you can bind an URL part with `/trophies/*game` so that it matches simply the whole remaining URL after trophies as documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaRouting).